# My Very Basic C++ Program Broke and I Have No Idea Why

Tags: c++

This is a program I am doing for programming class that that is supposed calculate people's pay depending on overtime and time and a half, but it broke and I have no idea why.

The thing will output "" "" has job 6942646 and worked 6923592 hours" or something like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string getName(string, string);
int getJob(int&);
int hoursWorked(int);
double jobCalc(int&, int&, double&);
void display(string, string, int, int, double);

int main()
{
int job;
int hours;
double pay;
string firstname, lastname;

getName(firstname, lastname);
getJob(job);
hoursWorked(hours);
jobCalc(job, hours, pay);
display(firstname, lastname, job, hours, pay);

return 0;
}

string getName(string firstname, string lastname)
{
cout << "Enter your name (First): ";
cin >> firstname;
cout << "Enter your name (Last): ";
cin >> lastname;    
return firstname, lastname;
}

int getJob(int job&)
{
cout << "Yo What motha duckin job number is you? Ya' dig? (10, 20, or 30): ";
cin >> job;

bool jobNo = false;
while (jobNo = false)
{
    if (job == 10)
    {
        jobNo = true;
    }
    else if (job == 20)
    {
        jobNo = true;
    }
    else if (job == 30)
    {
        jobNo = true;
    }
    else if (job < 9 || job > 11 || job < 19 || job > 21 || job < 29 || job > 31)
    {
        cout << "Yo! Please re-enter a correct value. What it is, mostly, Mama! Don't make me shank ya!" << endl;
        cout << "Yo What motha' duckin' job number is you? Ya' dig? (10, 20,   or 30): ";
        cin >> job;
    }
}

return job;
}


int hoursWorked(int hours)
{
cout << "Yo! How geezery hours dahd ya work?: ";
cin >> hours;
return hours;
}

double jobCalc(int& job, int& hours, double& pay)
{

if (job == 10)
{
    if (hours < 40)
    {
        pay = hours * 8.75;
    }
    else if (hours < 60)
    {
        pay = 8.75 * 40;
        hours = hours - 40;
        pay = pay + (hours * 13.125);
    }
    else
    {
        pay = 8.75 * 40;
        pay = pay + (13.125 * 20);
        hours = hours - 60;
        pay = pay + (17.5 * hours);
    }
}
else if (job == 20)
{
    if (hours < 40)
    {
        pay = hours * 12.25;
    }
    else if (hours < 60)
    {
        pay = 12.25 * 40;
        hours = hours - 40;
        pay = pay + (hours * 18.375);
    }
    else
    {
        pay = 12.25 * 40;
        pay = pay + (18.375 * 20);
        hours = hours - 60;
        pay = pay + (24.5 * hours);
    }
}
else if (job == 30)
{
    if (hours < 40)
    {
        pay = hours * 13.75;
    }
    else if (hours < 60)
    {
        pay = 13.75 * 40;
        hours = hours - 40;
        pay = pay + (hours * 20.625);
    }
    else
    {
        pay = 13.75 * 40;
        pay = pay + (20.625 * 20);
        hours = hours - 60;
        pay = pay + (27.5 * hours);
    }
}

return pay;
}

void display(string firstname, string lastname, int job, int hours, double pay)
{
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
cout << firstname << " " << lastname << " has job " << job << " and worked "          << hours << " hours, thus earning them $" << setprecision(2) << pay << "." << endl;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Had no idea you should to do that. Thanks.

Comment: From a glance it looks like you don't pass references with some of them (e.g. hours). That is probably the main problem.

Comment: In addition to the debugger, also learn to listen to compiler warnings. Usually, they warn you about some basic mistakes like while(jobNo = false) instead of == false.

Answer (score 0):

all of your functions are returning values. where you are storing it?. multiple return is not possible as you are using. try the concept of pointers(references)